# How to configure libgit2 in TFS Build with private repositories?

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, libgit2, libgit2sharp

I am currently using TFS 2013 (local installation) to try to build from an internal GitHub Enterprise installation using LDAP Authentication.

The problem I am getting is that it cannot access the source code, how can I configure TFS Build to use a specific authentication?

From the TFS Build Log

> Exception Message: An error was raised by libgit2. Category = Net (Error).
>
> VS30063: You are not authorized to access https://user:password@githubrepository.corp.company.net. (type LibGit2SharpException)
>
> Exception Data Dictionary:
>
> libgit2.code = -1
>
> libgit2.category = 11
>
> Exception Stack Trace:
>
> Server stack trace:
>
> at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Ensure.HandleError(Int32 result)
>      at LibGit2Sharp.Core.Proxy.git_clone(String url, String workdir, GitCloneOptions opts)
>      at LibGit2Sharp.Repository.Clone(String sourceUrl, String workdirPath, Boolean bare, Boolean checkout, TransferProgressHandler onTransferProgress, CheckoutProgressHandler onCheckoutProgress, Credentials credentials)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.GitPull.GitClone.GetRepository(String repositoryUrl, String workingFolder)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.AsyncProcessMessage(IMessage msg, IMessageSink replySink)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:
>
> at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.EndInvokeHelper(Message reqMsg, Boolean bProxyCase)
>      at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RemotingProxy.Invoke(Object NotUsed, MessageData& msgData)
>      at System.Func`3.EndInvoke(IAsyncResult result)
>      at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.GitPull.GitRepositoryBase.EndExecute(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity`1.System.Activities.IAsyncCodeActivity.FinishExecution(AsyncCodeActivityContext context, IAsyncResult result)
>      at System.Activities.AsyncCodeActivity.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityData.CompleteAsyncCodeActivityWorkItem.Execute(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)

**Follow up**

I have tried the URL params for authentication (example)

> https://username:password@domain.com/user/project.git

**More Follow up**

Completely uninstalled and update to the 2013 RC, error message has been updated as well, as it is different.

I have also tried setting up the build controller to run as an authenticated LDAP user in the github enterprise installation.

Answer (score 3):

Libgit2 does support the url credentials, however TFS build activities for GitPull overrides the default behavior with a Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Activities.Git.TfsSmartSubtransport class for the http and https protocol.

This class unfortunately ignores credentials in the URL and instead tries to retrieve credentials from the registry.

I was able to successfully get a TFS build server to pull source code from a gitlab server using TFS build with the default GitTemplate.12.xaml workflow.

Setup the TFS build's repository URL without any credentials in the URL.

Encrypted your credential's password with the following bit of code.  This needs to get run on the build server as the encryption process is specific to the local machine it's executed on.

```
var password = "your_password";
var bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(password);
var bytes2 = ProtectedData.Protect(bytes, null, DataProtectionScope.LocalMachine);
var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes2);
```

Add the following registry settings to your build server.

NOTE: The URL in the registry must exactly match the absolute URL of your repository or TFS won't find the credentials.

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TeamFoundationServer\12.0\HostedServiceAccounts\Build\http://githubrepository.corp.company.net]
"Microsoft_TFS_UserName"="<username goes here>"
"Microsoft_TFS_Password"="<bas64 encrypted password goes here>"
"Microsoft_TFS_CredentialsType"="Windows"
```

The only other alternatives to this approach that I could think of is to modify the default workflow and replace the GitPull activity with something else.

I'm not suggesting that this is the best method, but it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks for this, will check it out as soon as I get a chance, this might be the work around I needed.

Answer (score 0):

That's odd. It looks like the HTTP transport should [honor url-encoded credentials](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/a25519acc106acf6e1f376c81a078c78778015ed/src/transports/http.c#L158-L164).

In any case, it might be better and safer to set up the remote to get the credentials from elsewhere. The clone code is a good example of how to do this: [here's](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/a25519acc106acf6e1f376c81a078c78778015ed/src/clone.c#L313-L314) how to set up the callback, and [here's](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/blob/a25519acc106acf6e1f376c81a078c78778015ed/examples/network/clone.c#L66-L83) an example of how to generate the credential object.

Comment: Those links seem helpful if dealing with lib2git directly, unfortunately, I am using the TFS interface and the default builds.  Thanks for the links though.

Comment: Ah, sorry, I'm no TFS expert. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks anyway for the response. We may have identified that our setup of github enterprise may be the issue.

Comment: Hey Tom - if you figure out what the issue was with the setup then can you post back with the eventual answer (perhaps it was not supporting basic auth or something?) TFS Build should certainly be able to talk to other git repos to do builds so if it's not working then let us know.

Comment: @MartinWoodward I was unable to get it to work, still having issue with the invalid cert. With Git for Windows, I was able to set an environmental variable to allow invalid certs, but I have yet to find a work around for this one.

Comment: @TomAnderson I have run into the same issue as well.  I'm curious if you have solved it or what your workaround was.  If I can't get this to work, I'm looking at setting up a second remote in the Git repo and pushing to GitHub and a TFS Git repo.  That will let me keep using GitHub as the primary, and the push to TFS will kick off the CI build.  Not ideal, but workable.

Comment: @benb1n I worked with the TFS team a bit, and was finally told that I would need to write a custom build activity for it. I gave up for now, will try again at a later time.

Comment: I also used username:password and rest of the git link and I have the same problem...and it's a bottleneck...has anyone found out how to fix it? @MartinWoodward

Comment: @MartinWoodward, It appears that the GitPull activity overrides the default libgit2 subtransport with TfsSmartSubtransport which ignores credentials passed in the url.